# XQuery issue when counting empty nodes and nodes that don't have a specific text (ne)

Tags: xml, count, xquery, nodes, exist-db

I want to count all the `r` elements that don't have the text "unspecified" within them.

```
<!-- test.xml -->
<e>
<r/>
<r/>
<r>hi</r>
<r>there</r>
<r>you</r>
<r>all</r>
<r>unspecified</r>
<r>unspecified</r>
</e>
```

I am employing the following XQuery:

```
let $r_nodes := count(doc('test.xml')//r[text() ne 'unspecified'])
return
  $r_nodes
```

The `$r_nodes` variable gives me `4` not `6` as I was expecting,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string()` or even more compact, `.` instead of `text()` to correctly consider element that doesn't contain any text node :

```
let $r_nodes := count(doc('test.xml')//r[. ne 'unspecified'])
return
  $r_nodes
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare the *effective string value* of the text nodes (hence `text()`). Any empty element will not have a text node. So instead your query should look like:

```
let $r_nodes := count(doc('test.xml')//r[text() ne 'unspecified'])
return
  $r_nodes
```

In this way you compare the *effective string value* of the `r` element and not it's text nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the editing, so how can I get 6 instead of 4?

Comment: See my answer! That will give you `6`.

Comment: I think using string() instead of text() ??? , I tested it and that seems to solve my problem.